# Python web scraper post does not seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to post a single piece of text data to a web page to look up the warranty status of a device.  Every time I attempt this, I get 200 HTTP response codes, but the result is as if I had clicked the submit button with an empty NID field.  I am sure I am missing something simple, but it eludes me.  Here is my Python code:

```
 #!python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
REQUEST_URL = 'https://teamroom.tantalus.com/web/city-of-fulton/warranty-lookup'

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(REQUEST_URL, headers=headers)
print('REQUEST_URL: ',r.status_code)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
action = bsObj.find('form', id='warrantyLookup').get('action')
nid = {'nid':'0017B1CC64'}
r = s.post(action, data=nid, headers=headers)
print(r)
print('NID LOOKUP POST RESULT: ', r.status_code)
r = s.get(action, headers=headers)
print('NID LOOKUP RESULTS GET: ', r.status_code)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
warranty = bsObj.find('div', id='successMessages')
print('Warranty Results: ', warranty)
errors = bsObj.find('span', id='nid.errors')
print('Errors: ', errors.text)
```

Comment: maybe you need to encode the data, could you try to inspect the traffic in a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked how the post request really looks like?

You can do it with chrome for example.
Now you need to reproduce that post request with python.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did.  That is why I am using Beautiful Soup to extract the action URL, and using that in the post statement.  I then supply the NID in the data parameter of the post call.

I looked at the action URL most carefully in Chrome, and it does not appear that I need to change the values of the query parameters, so I am using the action URL unchanged.  Is that incorrect?

If one executes my Python code, leaving out the "headers" undefined errors you will get, the error condition returned is exactly as if the form was submitted with a blank NID field.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should look at OWASP ZAP and use a proxy with a browser. OWASP ZAP will give you more detailed information about the traffic that is going out from your browser. Then you could try to replicate the request. Maybe there is a redirect or something else going on that you can't see in chrome. One more thing. As you see there are also cookies involved maybe you have to pass them too or some other request information.

Comment: I will give OWASP ZAP a try.  

I thought that the Python requests library took case of cokkies and other session bookkeeping?